# Haskell: Conditionally execute external process with Maybe FilePath

Tags: haskell

I am struggling to understand a block of code which is extremely easy in imperative world.
That's what I need to do: given an executable full path, which is a Maybe FilePath type, I need to execute it conditionally.
If the path is a Nothing - print an error, if the path is Just Path - execute it and print message that the file has been executed. Only "Hello, World" can be easier,right?
But in Haskell I dug my self into numerous layers of Maybe's and IO's and got stuck.
Two concrete questions arise from here:
How do I feed a Maybe FilePath into a system or rawSystem? liftM does not work for me here.
What is the correct way of doing this kind of conditional branching?
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with simple `case` and pattern matching?

Comment: Have you tried pattern matching on `Maybe FilePath`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple pattern matching will do the job nicely.

```
case command of
  Just path -> system path >> putStrLn "Done"
  Nothing   -> putStrLn "None specified"
```

Comment: It is so easy when you know it. I got it now, the ">>" did it.

Comment: Although I know what ">>" does but I don't seem to be able to utilise it when needed. Thanks for the example of sequencing. But it does not show how to feed the Maybe value into the system function. I don't have the raw command string, I only have a Just path or Nothing. Below, I can see the Traversable solution. Is there anything else?

Comment: @r.sendecky: Well, one could have used `do { system path; puStrLn "Done"; }` for the `Just` case. As for "feeding the maybe value into the system function" - you can't. `system` wants a mere `String`, not a `Maybe String`. In any case, you have to unpack it (get the contained string) before calling `system`. And you have to handle `Nothing` somehow, e.g. you must not try to unpack it (would be an `error`). The `traversable` solution is just a shortcut to that.

Comment: @r.sendecky If you think the `>>` is the magic bit here, then you probably didn't understand hammar's answer. The magic bit here is the pattern match -- and it does, indeed, show how to feed either a `Nothing` or a `Just path` to the `system` command.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I got it. Thank you. I understood the branching with the pattern matching. But I also learned the sequencing. There is nothing special about the case statements but where to stick "putStrLn" afterwords would definitely puzzle me. Maybe I could not clearly express my confusion in the question. Asking correct questions is a skill too.

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you'd rather not pattern-match, use the `maybe` function:

```
maybe (putStrLn "None specified") ((>> putStrLn "Done") . system) command
```

That may occasionally be nicer than matching with a `case`, but not here, I think. The composition with the printing of the success message is clunky. It fares better if you don't print messages but return the `ExitCode` in both branches:

```
maybe (return $ ExitFailure 1) system command
```

Comment: Very nice and short. Very useful to learn. The command is not wrapped in Maybe though. Is the Traversable example above the only way of doing it?

Comment: Both, hammar and I (following hammar) have given the name "command" to the wrapped command, so command is either `Just realCommand` or `Nothing` (or bottom). If you want to have the IO-action return a `Maybe ExitCode` or similar, you can tack it on: `maybe (return Nothing) (fmap Just . system) maybeCommand`, but if you do it more than once, importing Data.Traversable and using traverse is less typing.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the `Traversable` type class was made for!

```
Prelude Data.Traversable System.Cmd> traverse system Nothing
Nothing
Prelude Data.Traversable System.Cmd> traverse system (Just "echo OMG BEES")
OMG BEES
Just ExitSuccess
```

Comment: I would dispute your first sentence, but yeah, traverse is very good for this too. +1

Comment: Yes, this works great. I don't understand it at all as yet but it works. It has not clicked even after reading on traversable unfortunately. It is so annoying when you see you stuff work but you don't understand why. Thanks very much for the example. If you have a minute I would appreciate a simplified explanation of traversables.

Comment: @r.sendecky If you haven't yet taken a look at the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/e/e9/Typeclassopedia.pdf), I highly recommend it. It has a great section on `Traversable` starting on page 31 of the Typeclassopedia (page 47 of the corresponding Monad Reader edition). If you read that and still feel a bit overwhelmed, say so, and I'll try to add my two cents.